# logging out of Okta hosted login page on mobile (React Native)

Tags: react-native, okta, openid-connect

I have a React Native app that uses Okta's hosted login page to authenticate.

When a user successfully authenticates for the first time through the PKCE flow, on every other login afterwards, they get automatically logged in as the same user.

I've used additionalParameters: { prompt: 'login' }, but it only asks for you to re enter your password and if you click signout, it brings you to a Citrix page that doesn't change anything about the flow - they still get logged back in as the same user after the fact.

I've tried using both the revoke and logout endpoints which actually changes the cookies a bit, but doesn't affect the flow same goes with restarting the app.

The only way is to clear hardware settings in xcode.

This may not even be an Okta specific issue, perhaps a general OIDC issue.

How does the hosted login page store and know you've previously logged in and how can that be fixed?

Comment: What SDK are you using? If it's [React Native AppAuth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth), there's an open issue for this. https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/issues/68

Comment: that's what I'm using, but it's been a while since anyone's responded to it. it seems more like a general oidc or Okta's implementation of it kinda thing. so I'm wondering if there are different solutions to it

Comment: You could try using our React Native SDK. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-react-native I haven't tried it myself.